# function not defined when calling 2 other functions

Tags: javascript

my function to call 2 functions is coming back as not defined updatea works fine updateb and updatec both come back as undefined, im trying to call updateb and then updatea using updatec.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });


    function updatea() {
    $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
    $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
  console.log(response, );
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
    console.log(item.beacon,item.delivery_avg,item.location)
         $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
    });
});

function updateb() {
    $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
    };

    function updatec(){
        updateb();
        updatea();
    }        
}
  var updatemyFunctionInterval = setInterval(updatec, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: your function `updatea` is only defined in the anonymous `$(document).ready` function and are not accessible after that from the outside.

Comment: Did you change the code or am I confused about the formatting now, weird..

Comment: In your code, updatec function is in the scope of updateb function. you should know that the function is visible only in its scope. so updatea cannot be called in updatec inside updateb as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updateb wrongly defined in updatea's context.
Run this -

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var row;
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item);
                $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
            });
        });


        function updatea() {
                $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
                $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
                console.log(response, );
                $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                console.log(item.beacon,item.delivery_avg,item.location)
                    $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
                });
            });
                
        }
    
        function updateb() {
            $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
        };
            
        function updatec(){
            updateb();
            updatea();
        }
        var updatemyFunctionInterval = setInterval(updatec, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have declared `updateb` as an internal function of `updatea` and `updatec` as an internal function of `updateb`.

You need to move the functions `updateb` and `updatec` out of function `updatea`.

Update to following

```
function updatea() {
    // your code 
}

function updateb() {
    // your code
}

function updatec(){
     updateb();
     updatea();
} 

var updatemyFunctionInterval = setInterval(updatec, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define functions in a common scope:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      var row;
      response.forEach(function(item, index) {
        console.log(item);
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
      });
    });


    function updatea() {
      $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function(index, item) {
          console.log(item.beacon,item.delivery_avg,item.location)
          $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
        });
      });
    }

    function updateb() {
      $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
    }

    function updatec(){
      updateb();
      updatea();
    }

    var updatemyFunctionInterval = setInterval(updatec, 5000);
  });
</script>
```